# Is it possible to have a div's background be an HTML5 video with the "contain" property?

Tags: html, video, background, contain

I'm looking to set a div's background as an HTML5 video/webm, and I was wondering if it's possible for it to have the "contain" property and maintain it's aspect ratio? I'm not looking to have the video cover the entire screen, but rather a div that stretches 100% of the width and a set height. I want the parts of the video that extend beyond the height threshold to be hidden?

Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say you don't what the video to completely cover the frame, but what you describe is exactly that.. But you cannot set a background to a video, but you can fill the div with the video then layer another div on top of that.

Comment: Ahh what I meant is that I do not want the video to fill the entire browser window (100% x 100%) but rather be contained within a div (the video acting as the div background). The div that the video would be contained in is 100% width and about 450px height. I want the video to act in the same way as an image would if it had the attribute "contain" i.e. clip what overflows from the bottom of the div when resized

Comment: Again you cannot set a video to the background attribute, but you can set the css on the video object and set the min-height and min-width attributes and overflow hidden and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

Its not a complete solution as I haven't found a way to make the video element respect the height of its containing div. It also seems to consume all the divs below it, I'm working on that now.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*===== Start HTML 5 Video DIV Background ===*/

.full-video {
  background: url(image) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  color: #6a6a6a;
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-cover {
  position: relative;
  height: 850px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-cover video {
  object-fit: cover;
  background-image: url(image) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-cover">
  <video class="video" muted autoplay loop playsinline poster="video/image">
    <source src="video/xxx.mp4"  type="video/mp4">              
    <source src="video/xxx.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/xxx.ogg"  type="video/ogg">
    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a css setup that I use and works pretty good.

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.